# Is it safe to stop thermald on my desktop PC?

Tags: 15.04, syslog

I have thermald running on my desktop PC, which is an older Xeon with 4 cores.

*thermald* pollutes the /var/log/syslog file on my 15.04. (See this related question, [How to quiet Ubuntu 15.04 noisy syslog](https://askubuntu.com/questions/630391/how-to-quiet-ubuntu-15-04-noisy-syslog))

It creates entries like this every 4 seconds:

```
Jun 23 16:01:08 xxx thermald[30886]: Set : 89000, 40000, 0, 0, 0
```

I could figure out how to change the config file to make it less noisy, so I turned thermald off completely (temporarily).

```
sudo systemctl stop thermald
```

Is this safe? Should I also blacklist the kernel module?