# Noise messages in the syslog from thermald

Tags: 15.04, syslog

I am running Ubuntu 15.04. I am noticing a lot of noise messages in the syslog from thermald.

```
thermald[9139]: Set : 94000, 25000, 0, 0, 0
thermald[9139]: Set : 94000, 26000, 0, 0, 0
thermald[9139]: Set : 94000, 25000, 0, 0, 0
thermald[9139]: Set : 94000, 26000, 0, 0, 0
thermald[9139]: message repeated 16 times: [ Set : 94000, 25000, 0, 0, 0]
```

Is my server going to melt or is there somewhere I can change the settings to stop these appearing in syslog or do I just have to live with it? I checked the cpu:

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0: +24.0°C (crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1: +22.0°C (crit = +100.0°C)
```

so that doesn't seem to be the problem. What else could it be?

Is it even useful on a server? Is it meant for laptops?

Comment: Just noticed my syslog full of these too - Ubuntu 14.04, 64-bit, running on a Dell XPS13. No idea what's causing it (nor indeed how long it's been happening), but at least you now know that you're not alone...

Comment: haha. I just turned it off @Scaine. Doesn't seem to be doing anything useful. And the messages have indeed stopped.

Comment: by the way I tried changing the log level as suggested in this post but it didn't work for me http://askubuntu.com/questions/630391/how-to-quiet-ubuntu-15-04-noisy-syslog?rq=1

Comment: Turns out, thermald only supports loglevel=debug (the default) or loglevel=info, which worked for me. I'll put a comment on that answer you linked to.

Comment: Nice one. Where did you find that, out of interest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 1.4.3-5 of thermald includes a fix to stop this log smapping:

thermald (1.4.3-5~15.04.1) vivid; urgency=medium

- Backport to vivid, fix debug spam in log (LP: #1494461)

See: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thermald/+bug/1494461

So this update should have fixed this issue